# Starting Activity Performs onResume?

Tags: java, android

Ok so I have this code in onCreate and onResume

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {  // After a pause OR at startup
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name2 = intent.getStringExtra(MyAdapter.KEY_VNAME);
        if (name2 == null){
            name2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainVoterView.KEY_VNAME2);
        }
        String Simage = intent.getStringExtra(MyAdapter.KEY_SUGGEST_IMAGE);
        if (Simage == null){
            Simage = intent.getStringExtra(MainVoterView.KEY_SUGGEST_IMAGE2);
        }

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Suggestion.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Suggestion.this);
        getData();
        adapter = new SuggestListAdapter(suggestList, Suggestion.this, name2, Simage);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

When I start the activity my suggestion feed is doubled.. and when I Pause the Application and then resumes it. The suggestion feed is fixed. What I'd like to ask is does onResume Activates when starting activity.

And if yes What method should I use ?

Why would they call it onResume if every time the Activity is called the onResume executes. For what I know that's not resuming.

Please do enlighten me

Comment: [Activity Lifecycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You get duplicates because the code is ran twice. An activity starting up from scratch goes onCreate, onStart, onResume, user sees the activity on screen. Once the application is paused you get a call to onPause and onStop (if the activity is not visible), and on resume you get a call to onStart and onResume.

There is a nice diagram and great explanation on the entire activity lifecycle in this [Google document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), this is a great read on this topic.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that, I've moved my codes into onResume only and that solves the problem.